# Why does C++ not allow user-defined operators?

Tags: c++, parsing, operators

I've been wondering this for quite some time. There are already a whole bunch of them and they can be overloaded, so why not do it to the end and allow custom operators? I think it could be a great addition.

I've been told that this would make the language too hard to compile. This makes me wonder, C++ cannot really be designed for easy compilation anyway, so is it really undoable? Of course, if you use an LR parser with a static table and a grammar such as

```
E → T + E | T
T → F * T | F
F → id | '(' E ')'
```

it wouldn't work. In Prolog, which is usually parsed with a Operator-Precedence parser AFAIK, new operators can easily be defined, but the language is much simpler. Now, the grammar could obviously be rewritten to accept `identifiers` in every place where an operator is hard-coded into the grammar.

What other solutions and parser schemes are there and what other things have influenced that design decision?

Comment: You have to draw the line somewhere I guess.  And yes, if you've ever tried to write a compiler you'll appreciate that they are not that easy to code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#overload-operator](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/bs_faq2.html#overload-operator)

> The possibility has been considered several times, but each time I/we decided that the likely problems outweighed the likely benefits.
>
> It's not a language-technical problem. Even when I first considerd it in 1983, I knew how it could be implemented. However, my experience has been that when we go beyond the most trivial examples people seem to have subtlely different opinions of "the obvious" meaning of uses of an operator. A classical example is `a**b**c`. Assume that `**` has been made to mean exponentiation. Now should `a**b**c` mean `(a**b)**c` or `a**(b**c)`? I thought the answer was obvious and my friends agreed - and then we found that we didn't agree on which resolution was the obvious one. My conjecture is that such problems would lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: Added the relevant quote. In general, simply posting links as answers is frowned upon on SO. It makes it harder for the reader to get an overview (if there are 5 different answers, and each of them contain a link and nothing else, it becomes a lot of work to figure out which answers are good and which ones are bad, or just irrelevant), but also because the page you link to may be taken down in the future, or the text on it may change. In short, if you want people to upvote your answer, then *you* have to contribute something. Even if it's just a direct quote from the page you linked to

Answer (score 2):

It would become even harder to compile than what already is. Also, there would be problems with operators' precedence: how do you define it? You need a way to tell the compiler that an user-defined operator has precedence over another operator.

Almost surely it's feasible, but I think that C++ doesn't need **other** ways to shoot yourself in the foot :-)

Answer (score 1):

This would make the language even more complex. And that obviously wouldn't be desirable.

Still, check out [Boost Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/). It goes a long way to make stuff like you mentioned possible using lots of template metaprogramming tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's designed to be very easy to parse and compile. C has 32 defined keywords, all other tokens are function and variables.

C++ only has a few more. One can easily identify which token is for which, so know what to look for when one uses the + token or whatever.

Comment: Easy to parse and compile? The general consensus is that C++ is one the hardest programming languages in existence to write a compiler for (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575143/writing-my-own-c-compiler/575155#575155).

Comment: Really, I couldn't believe that ... C++ sports a run-time type inference subsystem which is quite complex in it's own right, there are type deductions going on in template substitutions which aren't trivial, and also from the pure parsing step, I think some constructs are rather impressive (function pointers and typedefs being two things where my own C++ parser in my head sometimes finds its limits).

Comment: Compared to natural language parsing it is easy :), it's designed to be parsable by a machine with relative ease. Which similar languages are easier to parse is another question. ASM is undoubtedly the easiest from the machine point of view. And C would be easier than C++ as it doesn't have the operator overloading and templates. So to be fair, we should be comparing to other OOP languages and it's relatively equal compared to those.

Comment: C++ _is_ different than other OO languages. See what Walter Bright has to say (http://port70.net/~nsz/16_c++.html): "It's hard to parse because a particular sequence of tokens can produce multiple totally different parse trees, depending on what some of the symbols are declared as. Even worse, many of those symbols aren't known at parse time, because they aren't declared yet. So it has to be parsed into some indeterminate state that gets 'fixed' later. This issue makes it impossible to correctly parse C++ code without building most of a C++ compiler front end, including all the hard stuff."

Comment: That would even make java simpler ... maybe this is the reason why Netbeans and Eclipse do always accurate compiler error predictions while Visual Studio behaves rather erratic, sometimes finding errors where there are none, but most of the time simply not marking syntax/type errors which will show up later as obscure compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with allowing custom operators is that you also have to allow the programmer to specify the syntax for how the operators should be used. I suppose the C++ type system could help a little, but it would help resolving issues like associativity, etc.

It would make the already complex language, much more complex...

Answer (score 0):

This is usually avoided because most code is written by more that one man, so the code should be "reviewable", and it's hardly a "desired" feature of a language.

Joel Spolsky have a [good article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) about this.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it's actually possible to achieve something very similar to overloaded operators. Consider

```
Vector v, a, b; v = a /vectorProduct/ b;
```

Turns out you can achieve the behaviour of custom operator by using dummy classes delimited by existing operators. =)